# Polymorphic functions and type inference in SML

Tags: type-inference, sml

Consider this function in Standard ML.

```
fun times_until_zero(f, x) =
  if x = 0 then 0 
  else 1 + times_until_zero(f, f x)
```

REPL shows that `times_until_zero` has type `(int -> int) * int -> int`. But why isn't the type `('a -> int) * int -> int`? All I can see from the function definition is that `x` has to be `int` and `f` has to take an argument which is at least as general as `int` and `f` has to return `int`. I tested it together with a function binding `fun g x = 0` (so `g` has type `'a -> int`)  and `times_until_zero(g, 10)` returned 1 just fine.

Comment: This is a subtlety of Standard ML, and a common source of confusion, because it has to do with something that the language syntax leaves implicit. There's a good explanation at http://mlton.org/FirstClassPolymorphism, which you may find helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `times_until_zero` had the type you suggest, then a caller would be allowed to do the following:

```
times_until_zero (string_to_int, 10)
```

where `string_to_int : string -> int` parses a string into an integer. Clearly, the call to `f` would not be type-correct anymore.

The subtlety here is where `'a` is *quantified*, i.e., who gets to choose an instantiation. In the ML type system, the quantifier is always implicitly placed at the outermost position. That is, the type

```
('a -> int) * int -> int
```

actually means

```
forall 'a. (('a -> int) * int -> int)
```

Consequently, the caller of the function gets to pick a type for `'a`.

For your example to be type-correct, you'd need the type

```
(forall 'a. ('a -> int)) * int -> int
```

With this the callee, i.e., your function, gets to pick a type for `'a`, and can in fact pick a different one every time it calls `f`. On the flip-side, applying `string_to_int` would no longer be type-correct, since that function does not have the necessary polymorphic type.

However, types like the above with inner quantifiers (called higher-rank polymorphism) are not supported in plain ML, simply because type inference for them is not decidable in general.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But given that `times_until_zero` has type `(int -> int) * int -> int` and that the function `g` in my question has type `'a -> int`, why is the call `times_until_zero(g, 10)` legal?

Comment: Because the type of `g` can be instantiated to `int -> int`. That way round is no problem.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I think I mixed up type inference with type checking rules for higher-order functions.